# my page doesn't load the CSS files Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

[image] I called the CSS files in the public/index.html page and placed the css files in under the public folder and when i use a path of two dimensions like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/user/username1003
```

the CSS files doesn't load its like the page shows up with only html
but when i use a path like this

```
http://localhost:3000/username1003
```

it works perfectly any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react the usual way of importing `css` is in your `javascript` files. If they apply to all components you can import in the `index.js` file.
For example if you have a file `index.css` in the same folder you add this line on top of your file:
`import './index.css';`

Some style packages for react, like bootstrap, also need to be installed with npm, you can check more here: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: And what happened? Did it work?